# Rx swift keeping the original order of the original stream after using flatMap

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-swift

I'm trying to keep the original order to the stream after applying flatMap in the middle.

Here is the diagram to elaborate what I mean:

----2-4-1------------------ (Original stream)

-----------1--2---------4-- (Network activity - represented by flatMap with delay)

---------------2---------4-1 (The wanted outcome)

Here is a code to elaborate the situation:

```
    persistMessageEventBus.flatMap({ num -> Observable<Int> in

        print("aaab Doing \(num)")

        let t2g = Observable.just(num).delay(Double(num), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance).do(onNext:{ num in print("aaab Done async \(num)")})

        return t2g

    }).concatMap({ num -> Observable<Int> in

        print("aaab Done map \(num)")

        return Observable.just(num)

    }).subscribe(onNext: { num in

        print("aaab done \(num)")

    }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)

    persistMessageEventBus.onNext(2)
    persistMessageEventBus.onNext(4)
    persistMessageEventBus.onNext(1)
```

The output is:

```
aaab Doing 2
aaab Doing 4
aaab Doing 1
aaab Done async 1
aaab Done map 1
aaab done 1
aaab Done async 2
aaab Done map 2
aaab done 2
aaab Done async 4
aaab Done map 4
aaab done 4
```

The wanted output is:

```
aaab Doing 2
aaab Doing 4
aaab Doing 1
aaab Done async 1
aaab Done async 2
aaab Done map 2
aaab done 2
aaab Done async 4
aaab Done map 4
aaab done 4
aaab Done map 1
aaab done 1
```

Is there something like that in RxSwift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use .concatMap() instead, it guarantees the original order.

**UPDATE #1**

Then apparently it will require indexing and some buffering.

```swift
       typealias Indexed = (num: Int, index: Int)

        class Buffer {
            let ordered = PublishSubject<Int>()
            private var current = 0
            private var buffer: [Int: Int] = [:]
            func onNext(_ indexed: Indexed) {
                self.buffer[indexed.index] = indexed.num
                for index in self.buffer.keys.sorted() {
                    if index == current {
                        ordered.onNext(self.buffer[index]!)
                        self.buffer.remove(at: self.buffer.index(forKey: index)!)
                        current += 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        let buffer = Buffer()

        buffer
            .ordered
            .subscribe(onNext: { num in

                print("aaab done \(num)")

            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        persistMessageEventBus
            .mapWithIndex { (num, index) -> Indexed in
                return (num: num, index: index)
            }
            .flatMap({ indexed -> Observable<Indexed> in

                print("aaab Doing \(indexed.num)")

                let t2g = Observable.just(indexed).delay(Double(indexed.num), scheduler: MainScheduler.instance).do(onNext: { indexed in print("aaab Done async \(indexed.num)") })

                return t2g

            })
            .subscribe(onNext: { indexed in
                buffer.onNext(indexed)
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        persistMessageEventBus.onNext(2)
        persistMessageEventBus.onNext(4)
        persistMessageEventBus.onNext(1)
```

```
aaab Done async 1
aaab done 2
aaab Done async 2
aaab done 4
aaab Done async 4
aaab done 1
```

Comment: Yeah but then the network activity won't be in parallel So instead looking like this:  ---------------2---------4-1 the stream will look like this ---------------2-------------------------4-1

Comment: @Rotem see **UPDATE #1**

Comment: Thank you @maxim-volgin, that is pretty much what I've done in order to solve this, although the reason I've asked this question is because I was wondering if there is a native operator for this in Rx. Anyway, I will accept this answer, thanks and gg!